# Error: Cannot find module 'express' when running on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have a node.js app which uses express and runs locally with no problems. However, on Azure I am seeing:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

The packages.json file contains the dependency:

```
"express": "^4.15.3"
```

Assuming something had gone wrong with the `npm install`, I went to the Kudu remote execution console and ran `npm outdated`. No packages are missing.

This is my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.port || 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

require('./app/routes')(app);
app.listen(port, () => {
});
```

I'm assuming it is something very obvious, but I can't work out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Azure App Service is Windows environment, try to include `node_modules` in the `wwwroot`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much we can really help with here, as the error you have provided indicates that the `express` npm package has not been installed properly. So, I would suggest that you use **App Service Editor** (`https://[YouAppName].scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`) to troubleshoot this issue by checking whether the `express` folder exists in the `node_module`.

[image]

You can also run command `npm install` in the console, restart your app and run it (`Ctrl + F5`) in the browser.

[image]

Comment: In my case, it was because of failed deployment (Azure didn't notify though). You can go to `Deployment options` and check if it failed. Redeploying it seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

check your package.json, it should have express included.

it should be similar to this

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@azure/storage-file-datalake": "^12.12.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "brotli": "^1.3.0",
    "bson": "^2.0.4",
    "int53": "^0.2.4",
    "object-stream": "0.0.1",
    "snappyjs": "^0.6.0",
    "thrift": "^0.10.0",
    "varint": "^5.0.0"
  }
```